# Посчитать пропуски в списке

Tags: python, numpy

Второй и последний вопрос (впринципе этот вопрос можно решить через перебор `for i in`, но это много строк и не так как надо, наверняка есть проcтой способ).

Как поcчитать кол-во nan в списке `a = [np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]` между 3-мя числовыми последними значениями и получить по ним список? Тоесть в списке есть последнии 3 значения это 6,9,3. Начиная с конца и пропуская первые nan, кол-во nan между 3 и 9 = 3. Между 9 и 6 = 2. Между 6 и 8 = 1. В таком случае ответ будет `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что предлагаемое решение сильно уменьшит количество строк и будет самым эффективным, но попробовать можно так:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan])

for i in np.split(a, np.ravel(np.argwhere(~np.isnan(a)))):
    print(np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(i)))
```

получим:

```
2
1
2
3
4
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

A = [np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]
B = [len(list(y)) for x, y in groupby(A) if (x is np.nan)]
print(B)

>>[2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Так я ваш список из вопроса скопировал. Если у вас другой тип объектов, то и сравнивать надо с ним - ведь логично?

Comment: [nan,nan,8,nan,6,nan] а для такого работать вроде тоже должно - одно и тоже по сути

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос в том виде, как он был задан. Если у вас другой тип объектов - сравнивайте именно с этим типом.

Answer (score 0):

еще один похожий на уже предложенные способ:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.Series(a).dropna().index
res = [j-i-1 for i,j in zip(idx,idx[1:])]

print(res)  # [1, 2, 3]
```